# Find the outliers in data and replace them with mean of two consecutive values before and after that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with two rows. I want to replace the outlier in each rows with the `mean of value before and after it`. Honestly, I dont know how to exactly find the outliers. For example, for the first row, the values `20, 100, -10` are outlier. Since they are far from the mean values of most samples.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['id'] = [1, 2]
df['val1']= [5, 12]
df['val2']= [6, 12]
df['val3']= [7, 12]
df['val4']= [20, -20]
df['val5']= [5, 12]
df['val6']= [4, 13]
df['val7']= [8, 10]
df['val8']= [9, 12]
df['val9']= [100, 100]
df['val10']= [-10, 12]
df['val11']= [5, 13]
df['val12']= [8, 12]


       id val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8   val9 val10 val11 val12
   0    1   5    6      7   20  5     4   8     9    100    -10  5      8
   1    2   12   12     12  -20 12    13  10    12   100    12.  13     12
```

The desired output is:

```
id  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8 val9 val10 val11 val12
0   1    5     6    7    6      5   4   8   9   7   7   5    8
1   2    12  12     12   12     12  13  10  12  12  12  13  12
```

Honestly, I dont have any idea how to solve this. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: you need to come up with logic , according to your data what should be the range above which you will considered outlier,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [SciPy's](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/) Stats and [ZScore](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) to help find outliers. I was able to whip something up with the assumption that all negative values are outliers and that any value with a zscore of 2 or greater is also an outlier. I'm not sure how all of your data will look, so playing with the max zscore value might be necessary. Anyway, with the data you provided, I was able to get the same output you wanted:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id'  : [1, 2],'val1':[5, 12],'val2':[6, 12],'val3':[7, 12],
                   'val4':[20, -20],'val5':[5, 12],'val6':[4, 13],'val7':[8, 10],
                   'val8':[9, 12],'val9':[100, 100],'val10':[-10, 12],'val11':[5, 13],'val12':[8, 12]})

finalDF = pd.DataFrame()
for dfIndex in range(len(df)):
    # melt the row to work with it like a list
    meltList = df[dfIndex:dfIndex+1].melt().value  
    
    # Loop through the melted list removing all elements that have a zscore of more than 2
    badList = []    
    while True:
        zscores = stats.zscore(meltList)
        bad = np.unique([zscores[zscores==x].index for x in zscores if x > 2])
        if len(bad) < 1: # if there are no more zscores greater than two, stop the loop
            break
        for x in bad:
            badList.append(x)
            del meltList[x]
    # Find all values that are negative, as those are outliers too
    bad = [meltList[meltList==x].index for x in meltList if x < 0]
    for x in bad:
        badList.append(x[0])
    
    # Get the original melted list again (without the removed indexes)    
    meltList = df[dfIndex:dfIndex+1].melt().value
    
    # Sort the bad values list so that it can be used for the next loop
    badList.sort()
    # Change the outlier to the mean of the values it is sandwiched between
    # If the previous or next value are also outliers, find the next value that isn't an outlier
    for x in badList:
        prevVal = meltList[x-1]
        nextVal = meltList[x+1]

        n=1
        while x-n in badList:
            n += 1
            prevVal = meltList[x-n]
        n=1
        while x+n in badList:
            n += 1
            nextVal = meltList[x+n]
        meltList[x] = (prevVal + nextVal)/2

    # Get the original melted dataframe as a new variable
    newDF = df[dfIndex:dfIndex+1].melt()
    # Change the values in the new dataframe to the ones without outliers
    newDF.value = meltList
    # Set the index to the same value to be used to pivot the table
    newDF.index=[dfIndex]*len(newDF)
    # Pivot the now outlier free dataframe back to its original format
    newDF = newDF.pivot(index=None,columns='variable', values="value")
    # Combine all the rows
    finalDF = pd.concat([finalDF, newDF])

# Put the columns back in the correct order
finalDF[['id','val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6','val7','val8','val9','val10','val11','val12']]
```

Output:

```
id  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8 val9 val10 val11 val12
0   1    5     6    7    6      5   4   8   9   7   7   5    8
1   2    12  12     12   12     12  13  10  12  12  12  13  1
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'". Then I change the zscore to the list, I get another error. Could you please take another look? thanks

Comment: If you have a dataframe then you should have an index. Your question said "dataframe" not "numpy.ndarray"

Comment: Yes. I have df. But the error is for this line: "bad = np.unique([zscores[zscores==x].index for x in zscores if x > 2])"

Comment: Can you update your question with your entire code? e.g. also include where you define `df`

Comment: i've just updated the question. However, it does not change too much. Since I have a verrrry large dataframe and I only provide a sample of that here. I attached the figure for the df which I have.

Comment: Not that, somewhere in your code you have `df = ` something ... is it `df = pd.DataFrame()` ?

Comment: Yes. It is df = pd.DataFrame()

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code exactly? `meltList = df[dfIndex:dfIndex+1].melt().value` is using the column with name `value` so it is equivalent to `meltList = df[dfIndex:dfIndex+1].melt()["value"]` . Did you place `.values` somewhere? Because that would make an numpy array

Comment: No. I did not change anything. I just copied the block of code and run it. I just checked it and again I got that error.

Comment: When you run just my code (copy the above exactly, then run it, not with your data) does it run fine? If the above code runs fine, but it doesn't run when you try to add your data into my above code, then that means that you did not provide a good enough example of your data for me to work with.

Comment: When I copy the whole code with your data (df= pd...{'id'} it gets me the error. For my whole dataset, I also get the same error.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Maybe it is the version of your packages. I just checked on two separate computers and the code runs fine. I have `pandas version: 1.3.4`, `numpy version: 1.22.2`, and `scipy version 1.7.1` on one computer and `pandas version: 1.4.1`, `numpy version: 1.21.5`, and `scipy version 1.7.3` on the other. Maybe you are working on older verisons

Comment: Probably yes. I am working on the pods of my company and I can not change the version of the packages. Thanks for your patience. I will accept your answer.

Comment: I ran the code on my local laptop on my dataset and it works. Thank you again:)

Comment: Oh, great! I was going to work with np.arrays and switch out the `.index` part with `np.where` but I'm happy this works instead